# Group Characters and Centralizer of an element

Tags: representation-theory, characters

Let G be a finite group. $\hat{G}$ donates a set of all irreducible representations of G over $\mathbb{C}$. $C_G(h)$ denotes centraliser of an element $h\in G$. I want to prove
$|C_G(h)|=\sum\limits_{\chi \in \hat{G}}\chi(h)\overline{\chi (h)}$.

I dont know how to get this. Please help me with this.

Comment: What background do you have? Do you have any other version of Schur Orthogonality?

Comment: I had basic course on representation theory. I know, irreducible characters of G (over C) forms ortho-normal basis for space of class functions. @runway44

Comment: I found my question is nothing but a statement of another version Schur Orthogonality  @runway44

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can approach this by phrasing the character orthonormality in terms of matrices. So we will view characters as complex valued functions on conjugacy classes of $G$, and note that the orthonormality of irreducible characters can be expressed as: \begin{equation}\sum_{C}|C|\chi_V(C)\overline{\chi_W(C)}=|G|\delta_{V,W}\end{equation}

Where $V$, $W$ are irreducible representations, and $C$ runs over the conjugacy classes of $G$. Let $M$ be the character table, viewed as a $\text{#}C\times \text{#}C$ matrix. Then if $D$ is the diagonal matrix with $(C,C)$ entry equal to $|C|$, this equality becomes \begin{equation} MDM^*=|G|I\end{equation}

Where $M^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $M$. So rearranging this, we obtain \begin{equation}M^*M=|G|D^{-1}\end{equation}

Noting that $\frac{|G|}{|C|}$ is the cardinality of the centraliser of an element of $C$ yields your result by comparing entries of these two matrices.

Comment: I had understood this. Thanks. Also M*M is self adjoint matrix. @user277182.